# How to properly configure WebPack and TypeScript for some fat client development

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'd like to develop a webpage that I can attack scripts to that reside in a bundle.js file.

The problem is I can't for the life of me get my class to become visible to my html. I believe this must be a simple thing to do?

First, my typescript **first.ts**

```
export class Startup
{
    constructor(){    
        console.log("Startup class initialized!")  ;
    }


    ShowTime(todayDate : Date) : string {
        if(todayDate == null)
            throw new Error("todayDate cannot be null");

        return "Time supposedly is  -- " +  todayDate;         
    }

    public static worker = new Startup();
}
```

Then, I have the corresponding html file:

```
<html>
    <head>            
        <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="doIt();">Show Time</button>
        <br />
        <h2 id="h2Msg" style="color:red;"></h2> 
    </body>
    <script>

        function doIt(){
            var element = document.getElementById("h2Msg");
            element.innerHTML = Startup.worker.ShowTime(new Date());
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I have a working tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": 
  {
    "target": "es3",      /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2015", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,    /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "rootDir": "src/",    /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */   
    "outDir": "dist/",     
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*",
    "*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

Next up is package.config:

```
{
  "name": "testsetup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.47",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "run": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.test.ts"
  },
  "author": "digitaldias",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And finally, webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry : './src/first.ts',
  resolve : {
    extensions : ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      { test : /\.ts$/, loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader'}      
    ]
  },
  output : { 
    filename : 'bundle.js',
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')    
  }
}
```

When I run this using npm run, I see the constructor log message, however, I cannot attach to any of the code produced in bundle.js.

What I am trying to achieve is that when the button in the html is clicked the static instance of the **Startup class** method **ShowTime()** is called.

Should I even be using webpack for this, or are the other, easier ways to get this accomplished?

This is NOT a node.js question :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
<script>

    function doIt(){
        var element = document.getElementById("h2Msg");
        element.innerHTML = Startup.worker.ShowTime(new Date());
    }
</script>
```

You want to expose a *global* called `Startup`. Globals is *not* what modules are for.

ie. you would not do `export` and since you are not using modules

## More

I would recommend not doing globals and only using modules. You can move *all* code into your app and don't pollute `index.html`.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the point. I DO want to use modules, but first I need to understand how to reach them from html. The current configuration does not work. I cannot reach anything in bundle.js, and need to understand why. Ideally, my button.onclick() method should call into either a global or reach a module, but that doesen't work witht the above configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found what seems to be CLOSE to the answer to my own question:

Instead of trying to execute any of my typescript code, instead, I attached the necessary events from that code explicitly:

```
import { UserAgentApplication } from 'msal';

class Startup
{
    token : string;

    constructor()
    {    
        console.log("Startup class initiliazed")  ;
    }


    AddButtonClickEvent(){
        var button = document.getElementById("daButton");
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            var clientId  = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
            var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
            var app = new UserAgentApplication(clientId, authority, Startup.worker.onTokenReceived,);
            app.loginPopup(["User.Read"]);        
        }, false);
    }


    onTokenReceived(errorDesc:string, token:string, error:string, tokenType:string)
    {
        if(error.length == 0)
        {
            this.token = token;
            var e = document.getElementById("h2Msg");
            e.innerHTML = "Signed in";
        }
    }
    static worker = new Startup();
}


window.onload = function()
{   
    Startup.worker.AddButtonClickEvent();
}
```

The class **Startup** creates a static instance of itself, and then hooks up to the button in my html during the **window.onload** event.

Apparently, I cannot include a bundle.js and "hit" the code within it. If anyone knows how to do that, I'd be thankful!